# INTERNAL: error in frame handler in Android

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java, cosmos-sdk

I'm getting **java.io.IOException: FRAME_SIZE_ERROR: 4740180** error from following code

```
ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(GRPC_MAIN, PORT_MAIN)
                        .usePlaintext()
                        .build();
```

Here is the configuration in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.37.0'
implementation ('io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.37.0') {
exclude group: 'com.google.api'
exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf.GoGoProtos', module: "protobuf-java"
exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf.AnyProto', module: "protobuf-java"
exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf.AnyOrBuilder', module: "protobuf-java"
}
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.37.0'
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
```

Stacktrace:

```
Status{code=INTERNAL, description=error in frame handler, cause=java.io.IOException: FRAME_SIZE_ERROR: 4740180
at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2.ioException(Http2.java:597)
at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2.access$200(Http2.java:48)
at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.framed.Http2$Reader.nextFrame(Http2.java:138)
at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$ClientFrameHandler.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:1101)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
}
```

can anyone give me hint how can I get rid from this? Thanks!

Comment: This was answered at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/8164 right?

Comment: Yes.The problem was in server port.

Comment: Did you resolve this? facing a similar issue